# The line isnt showing in the navbar?

Tags: html, css

I was following a YouTube tutorial, in which a CSS hover and after effect was used so that when you bring you cursor on the navbar items, a line emerged gradually from the center. But the line isn't showing at all not when I bring the cursor on the navbar items and it didn't show when I wrote the `::` after code either I don't understand what is wrong ?

So this is the CSS code

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    padding: 2% 6%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: sticky;
}

nav img {
    width: 150px;
}

.nav-links {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
}

.nav-links ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav-links ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.nav-liks ul li::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #a85d58;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-liks ul li:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

And this is the Html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>University</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,700;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

    <section class="header">
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
            <div class="nav-links">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">COURSE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">BLOG</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>


    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First of all correct your typos - nav-liks should be nav-links. Second learn to use your browser dev tools inspect facility so you can track down this sort of bug (it would have been immediately apparent that your ::after CSS wasn't being applied). Once you have done that, have a look at what you are trying to transition - the width goes from 100% to 100%, ie nothing to transition. Next, make your code into a runnable snippet - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example This may help you understand what else is wrong, describe what's wrong alongside the runnable snippet.